# hubotのエラー

Tags: javascript, hubot

hubot実行時

> $ yo hubot
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
>                       throw err0;
>                       ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.config/configstore'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:843:18)
>       at Function.sync (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
>       at Object.create.all.get (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:38:13)
>       at Object.Configstore (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
>       at new Insight (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
>       at Object. (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:130:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:345:32)

chownでアクセス権限を与えようとする。

> $ sudo chown  $root -R
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules
>
> chown: `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules'
>   の後にオペランドがありません Try 'chown --help' for more information.

解決策がよくわかりません。教えて下さい。恐らく、rootが悪いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`sudo yo hubot`コマンドは試されましたか？

`mkdir`コマンドでエラーが出ているようです。rootディレクトリでは管理者権限がなければ`mkdir`を実行できません。

もしくは`chown`コマンドにオペランドを指定してみてはいかがでしょうか。"chown"で検索すると用例が見つかると思います。